# What's the probability that water will reach the destination?

Tags: probability

I'm doing practice problems in a book for studying purposes and I'm just stumped on how to solve this one. I've tried everything I can think of.

Water from source to destination can go through 8 different pumping stations (see Figure). Each of the 16 pipes lets the water through with probability p. What's the probability that water will reach the destination?

[image]

Comment: Can you find the probability that no water will get through?

Comment: I actually tried to think about that and was struggling with it as well.

Comment: @Haris $p^2 < p$ and the probability that water gets through is not lower when you add a second pipe.

Comment: Do it for just one station, then two.  You'll see the pattern.

Comment: The probability of $A$ or $B$ is harder to calculate than the probability of $ \neg A$ and $ \neg B$. If the probability of $A$ is $p$ then the probability of $\neg A$ is $1-p$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thanks. I misunderstood the question. I thought water will be sent to any one of the stations and from there to the destination. I now understand that all the pipes are "open". So water can potentially go through all stations simultaneously.

Comment: @Haris  Hold on, maybe I don't understand the problem.  I read the problem as saying "what's the probability that, for at least one of the eight stations, both the incoming and outgoing pipes are open?"  In which case your $p^2$ would be correct for a single station.  What do you now think the problem means?

Comment: @CyclotomicField using that logic, I determined that the probability of failure along a single path would be (1 - _p_)^16, and that the total probability of successfully reaching the destination would be 1 - (1-p)^16? Is that correct or am I still way off?

Comment: @lulu I now believe all the pipes are "open". So water can potentially go through all stations simultaneously. But I still have doubts. What if the incoming pipe to station 1 is open but the outgoing is closed, both pipes for station 2 are open, and all other pipes are closed? Will we consider it a success? Because part of the water may be trapped in station 1 and not reaching the destination. Am I overthinking?

Comment: @POZEIDYNS You got it. Well done.

Comment: @Haris I believe you are overthinking.  I can't see a clearly phrased problem along those lines.  My version is clear (which doesn't mean it's correct):  I imagine a very big source, capable of pushing water through all $8$ stations.  Each station has an incoming and an outgoing pump.  You win if, for at least one of those stations, both pipes are open.  You lose otherwise.

Comment: @CyclotomicField  How are you interpreting the problem?  It's clearly very different from my reading.

Comment: @lulu I think they're asking for the probability of water getting through is the probability that it gets through the first pipe, or the second, or the third and so on. So I'm assuming the the pumping stations are creating redundancy to ensure service.

Comment: @lulu Makes sense. So we have an agreement about what the question means.

Comment: @CyclotomicField  It seems to me that each pipe is associated with a unique station.  That's how it is drawn.  If the pipe from Source to Station $1$ is open but the pipe from station $1$ to Destination is closed, then that station is useless and can be ignored.  At least, that's my reading.

Comment: It would be good to edit this post with an authoritative interpretation. I gather it is, "What is the probability that at least one of eight stations has both its input pipe and its output pipe open?" but that should be confirmed.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some dispute as to the problem statement, so I'll present my interpretation and solve that one.  Of course, my interpretation might be wrong.

My Interpretation:  There is a big source of water, capable of delivering water through all eight stations simultaneously, if all the stations happen to be working.  Each station has an incoming and an outgoing pipe.  Each of those pipes is open with probability $p$, independently of all the other pipes.  We are asking for the probability that water makes it from Source to Destination, hence we are asking for the probability that there is at least one station for which both incoming and outgoing pipes are open.

Solution:  Let's compute the probability that all stations fail.  A given station is working with probability $p^2$ (you need both pipes open).  Thus a given station fails with probability $1-p^2$.  Thus all eight stations fail simultaneously with probability $(1-p^2)^8$.  It follows that the desired result is $$\boxed {1-(1-p^2)^8}$$

Comment: I see now. This is clearly the correct interpretation. I should have looked at the picture more carefully.

Comment: Yeah, it took some interpreting. :)

Comment: @CyclotomicField  No worries.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! Much appreciated. :)

Comment: @POZEIDYNS If this answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark. Not only does it reward the answerer but is also helpful for others with a similar question in the future.